# how to find the smallest square surface for a specific city in array java

Tags: java, arrays

```
public clas Qyteti {
    public float getSiperfaqja() {
        return siperfaqja;
    }
}


public clas Shteti {
    Qyteti [] qytetet;

    public void qytetiMeIVogel() {

    }
}
```

This is my code, i created an obj array named qytetet My homework is
to find the smallest city in array calculating by square   surface.
qytetiMeIVogel should to calculate the smallest square surface.

`qyteti = city`

`siperfaqja = square surface`

Comment: Can you give us some more information? What does the array represent, what values are stored in it...

Comment: `clas` , are you sure ????

Comment: Yes of course but first of all im new here that's i wasnt clear so much, array represent cities, Qyteti is type of object and qytetet[] is the array. In qytetet[] i stored different cities with names.

Comment: It just a technical mistake here, i think i couldnt create arrays or objects without knowing how to write the class.

Comment: You need to loop through your array, and pick out the city with the smallest square surface. You can define a variable which keeps the city with the currently smallest square surface, and then return that city when the loop has finished.

Comment: What you posted isn't valid code. Apart from the `clas` typo you also return a variable `siperfaqja` that never got defined. But to get you started on your actual problem: You have to iterate through your `qytetet` Array and check if the square surface of the current iteration is smaller than everything you found before.

Comment: I already defined but i thought it wasnt necessary to mention that , just be patient with me because i said that im new here ahahaha,                                                                                      public Qyteti(String shkurtesa, String emertimi, float siperfaqja)
 {
  this.shkurtesa=shkurtesa;
  this.emertimi =emertimi;
  this.siperfaqja=siperfaqja;
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't really much to go on, but here is how I would do it:

```
    public class City {
    private  int squareSpace[];
    public void getData(){
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      squareSpace[] = new int[10];
      System.out.println("Please enter the square spaces of 10 cities\n");
      for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        sqaureSpace[i]=sc.nextInt();
      }
      //sc.close();
    }
    public int findMin(){
      int minValue=squareSpace[0];
      for(int i=1;i<10;i++) {
        if(squareSpace[i]<minValue)
          minValue=squareSpace[i];
    }
 }
```

I have assumed a static value of 10 here, but you can go ahead and assume any value. Now all you need to do is call the getData() and findMin() wherever required.

Comment: this helped me a lot, i didn't make this code because i must not use the Scanner in this case, but i took the logic you used. Thank you so much Alan

Comment: Happy to be of help. If not Scanner what have you used to get an input from the user?

Comment: i put the cities by method 'public  String shtoQytetin (Qyteti q)
 {
  if(q==null){
   return "Nuk mund te shtohet spse eshte null";
  }
  if(exists(q)){
   return "Nuk mund te shtohet pasi ekziston";
  }
  if(pozita==qytetet.length){
   return "Nuk mund te shtohet pasi nuk ka vend";
  }
  qytetet[pozita++]=q;
  return "Qyteti u shtua me sukses";'